# How to compare two arrays and remove unmatched record

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays , I want to compare both arrays by object index `{index:...}` . If index is not match then I want to remove that object from array .

**Array 1**

```
[
Text Field 32: {fieldName: "Text Field 32", fieldType: "text", index: 0, data: "valu1"},
Text Field 53: {fieldName: "Text Field 53", fieldType: "text", index: 1, data: ""},
Text Field 64: {fieldName: "Text Field 64", fieldType: "text", index: 2, data: "value 3"},
Text Field 65: {fieldName: "Text Field 65", fieldType: "text", index: 3, data: "value 4"}
]
```

**Array 2**

```
[
Text Field 32: {fieldName: "Text Field 32", fieldType: "text", index: 0, data: ""},
Text Field 64: {fieldName: "Text Field 64", fieldType: "text", index: 2, data: ""},
Text Field 65: {fieldName: "Text Field 65", fieldType: "text", index: 3, data: ""}
]
```

**Note:** As you see in Array 2 `{index:1}` is missing . Could someone please help me how to remove object which don't match .

**Expect Result**

```
  [
    Text Field 32: {fieldName: "Text Field 32", fieldType: "text", index: 0, data: "valu1"},
    Text Field 64: {fieldName: "Text Field 64", fieldType: "text", index: 2, data: "value 3"},
    Text Field 65: {fieldName: "Text Field 65", fieldType: "text", index: 3, data: "value 4"}
    ]
```

Comment: Hi, do you need to remove the object from Array 1, right?

Answer (score 1):

This function takes in two arrays, left and right. It returns left filtered to only include items with `index`s in the right array's `index`s.

```js
function matching(left, right) {
    const right_indices = right.map(r=>r.index);
    return left.filter(l=>right_indices.includes(l.index))
}
```

Note that I am *not* modifying the original array.

So, if you have:

```js
var Array1 = [...blahblah];
var Array2 = [...blahblah];

// You need to reassign Array1:

Array1 = matching(Array1, Array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that this way:

```js
var firstArray = [
 {fieldName: "Text Field 32", fieldType: "text", index: 0, data: "valu1"},
 {fieldName: "Text Field 53", fieldType: "text", index: 1, data: ""},
 {fieldName: "Text Field 64", fieldType: "text", index: 2, data: "value 3"},
 {fieldName: "Text Field 65", fieldType: "text", index: 3, data: "value 4"}
];

var secondArray = [
 {fieldName: "Text Field 32", fieldType: "text", index: 0, data: ""},
 {fieldName: "Text Field 64", fieldType: "text", index: 2, data: ""},
 {fieldName: "Text Field 65", fieldType: "text", index: 3, data: ""}
]

var result = secondArray.filter(x => firstArray.find(y=>y.index == x.index));


console.log(result)
```

Comment: Probably want to swap `id` out for `index`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr1: any = [
{fieldName: "Text Field 32", fieldType: "text", index: 0, data: "valu1"},
{fieldName: "Text Field 53", fieldType: "text", index: 1, data: ""},
{fieldName: "Text Field 64", fieldType: "text", index: 2, data: "value 3"},
{fieldName: "Text Field 65", fieldType: "text", index: 3, data: "value 4"}
]

const arr2: any  = [
{fieldName: "Text Field 32", fieldType: "text", index: 0, data: ""},
{fieldName: "Text Field 64", fieldType: "text", index: 2, data: ""},
{fieldName: "Text Field 65", fieldType: "text", index: 3, data: ""}
]



const updatedArr = arr1.map((arrItem: any) => {
    const sameValue = arr2.find((arr2Item: any) => {
        return arrItem.index === arr2Item.index
    })
    if (sameValue) return sameValue 
})

console.log(updatedArr)
```

Comment: This approach produces `undefined` items in the resulting array, rather than removing them.

Comment: It is weird, because I tested in a playground and it returned me the right result array